# Installing latest titanium studio on latest Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, titanium, ubuntu-14.04

So, I just set up Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit. I want to set up the Titanium Studio now on my machine. Please help me with the installation. Like from where to start and what to install/download. I don't want to mess up the environment as I had done last time.

I do know the official website but somehow that confuses a lot and hence, If someone has written any guide or something, link to that would be great. I was having issues with the titanium sdk versions. i.e. the Project developed on Mac with 3.2.3 wasn't working and vice versa.

Please help.

Comment: the official docs is probably the best you're gonna get, just make sure you read it thoroughly.

Comment: I am waiting to see If anyone has written a blog or something, that would be a better help. And of course, docs are best but somehow I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP specifically requested for the link to an article/guide for setting up Titanium Studio in Ubuntu 14.04, I am providing the link to that guide.

http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/04/19/how-to-install-appcelerator-titanium-studio-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts-64bit-linux-step-by-step/

Comment: This answer is good, but at the same time, It confuses a lot by giving links here and there. But now I have learned this hard way. Will post an article written by self soon. :)

Comment: @Suraj that would be great.